# PHP show one select object, from multiple arrays

Tags: php

how can i show "prijs" with the number behind it, and leave the rest out. I tried to do this for an experimental school project.
It should display:

> prijs: 19.99
>
> prijs: 22.5
>
> prijs: 25.5

```
<?php
function prijsLijst($titel, $auteur, $genre, $prijs) {
echo "$prijs de prijs.<br>";
}

$boeken = array (
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 19.99),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 22.50),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 25.50)
    );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach and echo the element you want. please see the below code, it may help you

```
  $boeken = array (
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
 "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 19.99),
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
  "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 22.50),
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
 "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 25.50)
);

foreach($boeken as $single)
{
    echo "prijs ".$single['prijs'].' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 array_walk_recursive($boeken, 'prijsLijst');
 function prijsLijst($item) {
    echo "prijs: ".$item['prijs']." ";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need. Just iterate on the outer array and get the prijs key on each one:

```
<?php
function prijsLijst($array) {
  $result = '';
  foreach($array as $item)
  {
    $result .= "prijs: ".$item['prijs']." ";
  }
  return $result;
}

$boeken = array (
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 19.99),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 22.50),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 25.50)
    );

echo prijsLijst($boeken);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$boeken = array (
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams","genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 19.99),
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams","genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 22.50),
  array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams","genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 25.50)
);

foreach($boeken as $item){
  echo "prijs: ".$item['prijs']."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take count of array and use loop to count and echo value this is perfect way to echo  your value how you want.

```
<?php 
$boeken = array (
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 19.99),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 22.50),
array("titel"=> "Stoner", "auteur" => "John Williams",
    "genre" => "fictie", "prijs" => 25.50)
    );
 $count= count($boeken);
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    $value= $boeken[$i]['prijs'];
    $name= array_search("".$value."",$boeken[$i]);
    echo $name.": ".$value."  ";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can perfectly display your data  how you want thanks